# iPhone 5 Video Format

Tags: iphone, video

I'm using MPMoviePlayerViewController (for an app that will run on the iPhone 4 AND iPhone 5) as follows:

```
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videoFile ofType:videoType]];  
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];  
    moviePlayerVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:moviePlayerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer;

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                               object:moviePlayer];  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification 
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayer play];
```

but the video editors need to know what video size to use (i.e. to cater for both the iPhone 4 and iPhone 5).

Looking at Apple's docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html

under Video Technologies it states:

640 by 480 pixels

So, what video size would be best for both the iPhone 4 and 5.

E.g, should the video editors export video at 640 x 480 pixels?

Or should they export at 1136 x 640 (i.e the iPhone 5 screen size)?

Or perhaps 960 x 640 (iPhone 4)?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted from the Apple documentation, the maximum supported resolution is 640 x 480 so there wouldn't be any additional advantage in having the videos exported at any higher resolution than that.

> The video technologies in iOS support the playback of movie files with
> the .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp filename extensions and using the
> following compression standards:
>
> - H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second,
>   Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio
>   up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file
>   formats
> - H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per
>   second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160
>   Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple
>   Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in
>   .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats